# Dev Express Aspx Menu and Font Awesome

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to use Font Awesome Icons within the Dev Express AspxMenu, I have to use the Template Property in order for it to show up but now the Text Link doesn't show up and the click event obviously is broken. Has anyone done this before?

Here is the Code:

```
<dx:aspxmenu id="ASPxMenu1" runat="server" allowselectitem="true" backcolor="Transparent"
            border-borderstyle="None" orientation="Horizontal" font-size="1.1em" forecolor="MidnightBlue">
    <Items>
        <dx:MenuItem Text="Planning" ItemStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-HoverStyle-BackColor="Transparent" ItemStyle-HoverStyle-ForeColor="#66ff33" ItemStyle-HoverStyle-Border-BorderColor="Transparent" Name="Employees">
            <Template>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" style="color:white;"></i>
            </Template>
        </dx:MenuItem>
        <dx:MenuItem Text="Dashboard" Name="Dashboard" Visible="false"></dx:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</dx:aspxmenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template does not include the text. Try something like this:

```
<Template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="Label1" Text='Planning' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</Template>
```

Add an anchor tag and javascript to handle toggling the checkbox if that's part of your plan.